# Cookies from https to http works sometimes, sometimes not

Tags: http, cookies, https

I have a website with a login form in https which sets a session id in a cookie. For some reasons, the rest of the webpage is a cgi-script from http. However, when accessing the cookie from http, it *sometimes* work, sometimes not, although I can clearly see the cookie is set to correct session id in the browser. I have not yet discovered a pattern. Am I missing something?

```
https://mypage.com/secure/login.php
http://mypage.com/cgi-bin/script
```

I set the cookie path to "/", which should do the trick, right? Domain is set to ".mypage.com". Secure only is false, http only false.

Tested with Firefox and Chromium.

Regards
Olle

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I'm afraid I don't remember, and I'm busy with other projects at the moment. Did you have a similar problem?